# Is there an app such as GoodReads for movies?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, applications

I like the app [GoodReads](http://itunes.apple.com/be/app/goodreads/id355833469?mt=8), and I'm looking for something similar for movies.
Is there any app you can suggest me?

It should be able to make a collection of the movies I saw/own and to share lists, items,... on social networks (Facebook, Twitter,...)

Comment: yeah i have the same question as yours. I am a big movie fan.I can watch any movie,any time,any place.And i want something like what goodreads give us the chance to let our friends know what we are reading,want to read or have read.IMDb is a great place for movie lovers.But yet again the point is we want to share it with our friends too. stuff like that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options you can use here. They can do practically the same:

#### [Flikster](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/movies-by-flixster-rotten/id284235722):

It's an app which will allow you to create watchlist and share them with your friends. And you can even write reviews for movies and share them with your friends.

#### [IMDB](http://itunes.apple.com/app/imdb-movies-tv/id342792525?mt=8):

My personal favorite since it has the biggest library and community. You can watch trailers, share items, see actors, make cross-references, share movies with your friends and make watchlists. I personally enjoy using this app!

**And something out of category**:

#### [GetGlue](http://itunes.apple.com/be/app/getglue/id377615302?mt=8):

Here you can check into movies/books/shows/music/... you saw/read/watched/listened. And you can *follow* your friends and by so, see what they've been up to. It's not really what you want, but it's the closest I could find!

Comment: But where is the social network ? I can't add my friends and see their movies on both apps

Comment: Ah, that's what you mean by social media... I thought different. No, you can't add friends to neither of these apps...

Comment: What did u think I meant for social network ? So there are no similar apps to goodreads ?

Comment: IMDB is great, I'm using it, but I would like to see my friends movies sometimes..

Comment: By social media I thought you meant sharing on them. Share you watchlist, share your favorite movies,... If you want to see your friends movies, see my updated answer!

Comment: ok thanks, I guess there is room for a huge hit. Someone will soon publish such app and it will be quite popular

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, Rinema.com

Check out: [Rinema Features](http://www.rinema.com/features)

Feature Details

*Movies:* Add, Rate, Review, tag, link...

These little buttons, pretty much everywhere on the site, should come in handy to rate, review or mark a movie as "watched" or "to watch". And, while you review the movies you can also tag them (using the good old #tags) and link them to other movies by taggin them as done in the review below.
Review

To tag a movie, write the movie name in square brackets. So, [[The Shawshank Redemption]] will show as The Shawshank Redemption

*Discuss...*

Apart from using these little buttons to vote up/down and adding comments. You can also post updates through the homepage. And, you can tag movies, add #tags or tag your friends in them.

Oh! and you can see all conversations about a movie on the conversations tab on every movie page

*Lists...*

Hop over to the lists page & check out some of the lists that others have created. Or better yet, create you own. It's easy peasy.

*Search...*

Use the search box on the top nav to search for any movie (by name), Celebrity or user.

If you are looking for a particular movie, but are unsure of the title or wish to search by cast/crew names or just want more options, hop over to the advanced search page (second last option in the dropdown menu)

*Discover...*

The Movies link in top nav will take you to our movie suggestions page where we show you some movies that you might want to check out. You can also refine suggestions by a particular genre and/or language.

The best suggestions though are always from people whose tastes you share. So, use the cinephiles link on the top nav to find interesting people to follow. Or invite your friends.

You can also toggle your updates feed on home page to show updates from all users or reviews(from all users). And, use that to find interesting people & movies.

*Collections...*

You can add movies to various collections via this dropdown accessible from mymovies, individual and review modals.

we've have given three: Must Watch, Favourites, Guilty Pleasure to get you started with but, you can add as many new ones as you want. Just type the new name in the textbox and press Add. You can also delete collections using the [edit collections] link given in the collections list on the my movies page (towards the top).

Answer (score 1):

Funnily enough it is called **Goodfilms** - A social film review site, focusing on what your friends are watching, and what they thought of it:

http://goodfil.ms/

(As I have never used the site personally, I cannot comment further. If appropriate you may convert this answer to a comment if need be.)

Answer (score 1):

Goodshows just released beta app for iOS.

It lets you:

1. Rate and review all your favourite TV shows and movies.
2. Keep track of all your favourite shows and movie releases by adding them to your watchlist.
3. Keep an eye on what your friends are watching at all times.
4. Follow famous movie critics and like-minded reviewers and discover new movies and shows to watch.
5. Share your ratings and reviews with your friends on Facebook and Twitter.

Sign up here.
http://www.goodshowsapp.com/

Answer (score -1):

SeenTh.at is in private BETA now. I helped create the site over the past year and we'll be launching to the public later in the year.  You can read more at http://seenth.at/blog.

Comment: Nice, but what about the app ?

Comment: Still in private beta?

Answer (score -1):

Try [Letterboxd.com](http://letterboxd.com), we’re a social network, diary and list-making tool for film fans…

Comment: This is actually a great answer.